# Restart log shipping when out of sync

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo, failover

The scenario is. A database secondary server are for different reason out of sync or is suspected that is not sync.  Someone has made the secondary databases online by mistake or other mishaps. If you now want to make sure that they are set back on track. How do you do that? Preferably swiftly and for many databases at once.

When you set up a log shipping between two servers using the guide it takes care of the initial backup and copying of backup file and then the initial restore.
If I have to redo that I have to unable/enble and redo the  loghipping and fill all the parameters again. Is there an other way? Can I use [sqllogship application?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283327.aspx)
I there a "`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\sqllogship.exe`" -Restart -server SQLServ\PROD2
Or is there something that could be done easily with powershell and [SQL Server Management Objects - SMO?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd938892%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

I want to use all the parameters that are already in tables like `log_shipping_secondary`.

I have not found any scripts for doing this. I looked at the generated script when I used the guide but that does not contain the inital backup and copy. I can write my own script. I am just afraid someone will say: Why did you not just run: $smoLogShipping.Redo

Answer (score 0):

If you bring a standby database on-line (i.e.) restore it with_recovery then this will break the log-shipping. The only way to re-establish log shipping is to restore the standby database from a full backup of the source again and use no_recovery / standby mode.

Comment: >The only way to re-establish log shipping is to restore the standby database from a full backup.

Comment: >The only way to re-establish log shipping is to restore the standby database from a full backup. 
Yes I have understood that. I wondered if there was a feature to do these steps automatically. Since all the information about logshipping is stored in log_shipping_secondary.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any community supported script to do what you ask but it can be scripted easy enough. The GUI can handle most of the process, you would then just need to tweak it be parameterized and customized to the work flow that you are after. The link below gives an example of what I'm talking about.

[Scripting Log Shipping Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127668/scripting-log-shipping-automation)